# Looking for a quick way to make all of my form fields read only

Tags: javascript, php

I have a form that contains fields that should be read only for certain user types. Right now, I'm adding this code to each field:

```
<?php if($_SESSION['userFlag'] == 2 || $_SESSION['userFlag'] == 3) { ?> readonly <?php } ?>
```

This works, along with some hidden variables to make sure the data still gets written to the database, but I'm wondering if there's a faster way to lock those fields. One form in my application has close to a hundred fields, and it would be nice to be able to do this without so much repetition.

Comment: what about a function? like `readOnly(allowedUsersArray, value_to_print, value_if_reject)` not exactly that but something.

Comment: Alternatively IIRC a disabled <fieldset> will disable its children

Comment: I hope by the use of your hidden variables you mean you're taking into consideration the fact that "readonly" POST data can still be manipulated by the user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't perform the check on every line. Try assigning the value to a variable:

```
<?php
    if($_SESSION['userflag'] === 2 || $_SESSION['userflag'] === 3){
        $readonly = ' readonly';
    }
?>
```

Then on your HTML just add that line:

```
<input type="text"<?php echo $readonly; ?> />
```

If the flag isn't `2` or `3`, it will just be blank, but if it is then it will print `readonly`. This way you only perform the check once at the top.

Another possible improvement is to use `in_array`, which returns a boolean:

```
<?php
    $readOnlyFlags = array(2,3);

    if(in_array($_SESSION['userflag'],$readOnlyFlags)){
        $readonly = ' readonly';
    }
?>
```

This way you can easily change or add flags that match the `readonly` criteria, and it may also be a touch quicker performance-wise.